# srand(n) giving same values for any n

Tags: c++

```
void generator() 
{
    int n = <some number>;
    srand(n);
    int first = randint(9);
    digits.push_back(first);
    while (digits.size() < 4) 
    {
        bool flag = true;
        int num = randint(9);
        for (int j = 0; j < digits.size(); j++) 
        {
            if (num == digits[j]) 
            {
                flag = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (flag == true) 
        {
            digits.push_back(num);
        }
    }
    for (int i : digits)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
}

int main() 
{
 generator();
}
```

This code is supposed to generate 4 random and distinct digits on execution.
 
randint(x) is a function which generates a single random value anywhere between 0 and x.
 
While my digits are distinct, they aren't random. No matter what value I put inside srand(), I'm getting the same four digits:

> 2 4 5 1

Help me out if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: what value has `n`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mre]. What, for example, is `randint`? What does it do?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you might consider `std::unordered_set` instead of `std::vector`, as that will simplify your code a bit.

Comment: @Raildex `n` is just some random integer I'm changing manually to check if my logic works.

Comment: If there's a problem generating random numbers, then the function generating those random number is a very likely source of the problem, So please show it.

Comment: Is `srand` [`std::srand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand)? Are you seeding it with the *same* value every time?

Comment: @Bob__ It's from a header file called `std.lib.facilities.h` which is a compilation of most libraries of c++ and some additional stuff so pretty much yeah

Comment: @Bob__ No, I have tried different values but they are all giving me the same result.

Comment: See the answer below, then. Note, though, that the reseeding should usually be done once in the program, unless you want to produce the same sequence multiple times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::experimental::randint` is coupled with `std::experimental::reseed` to set the seed per thread: `srand` will have no effect on the generated output. You'll probably find that `randint` is automatically seeded with a constant value which accounts for your output. As it never became part of the C++ standard, I cannot comment further with certainty.

This is all non-standard, all non-portable, and best avoided from C++11 now we have `<random>`.